# Connected spaces where all subsets are either open or closed

Tags: general-topology

In the [Sierpinski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpinski_space), every nontrivial proper subset is either open or closed, but never both, fulfilling the slogan “A door is always open if it isn’t closed.”

More generally, every space endowed with a [particular point topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_point_topology) yields such an example.

Are there any more interesting examples? Are there Hausdorff spaces (apart from the singleton space, of course)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Door_space

Comment: If $\mathcal U$ is an ultrafilter on a set $X$, then $\mathcal U\cup\{\emptyset\}$ is a topology on $X$ making it a connected door space. A one-point topological space is a Hausdorff connected door space.

Comment: @bof Ah, neat. Thanks. One-point spaces being the least interesting examples imaginable, though. But the link actually proves there are no other.